# command to install 32bit packages (lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6) on ubuntu 16.4 LTS

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, 64-bit, libraries, android-studio

i want to install android studio 2.1 on my Ubuntu 16.4 LTS 64 bit so i follow the instructions on android developer guide web sit provided by google .. and they say i should install 32 bit libraries because android studio use them .

my problem is when i type the command :

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

i got this error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'lib32bz2-1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'
```

Comment: Don't. Better method: install virtualbox and install a 32-bit version of Ubuntu inside that and use that for coding it. It is far less hassle.

Comment: see if my answer works. I did not have a system to test if it did install android studio (so comment/pm me and I will add more).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should keep your system free from 32-bit software.  32-bit is on the way out and never to come back. Get used to 64-bit. If possible ignore 32-bit software. Now that my opinion is out here ...

Your best method is it to install virtualBox or VM Ware player and install a [32-bit Ubuntu](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent?_ga=1.256821128.260058970.1458070813) (links to the torrent of 32-bit 16.04.1) in it. Then install android studio. It will work better than mixing it up with your current install.

---

If you still want to install it in your current system then the method to install 32-bit should be to add the architecture, update and it then should have imported the 32-bit packagea,

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1
```

This will show ...

```
...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gcc-5-base:i386 gcc-6-base:i386 libgcc1:i386 libgpm2:i386 libtinfo5:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-5-base:i386 gcc-6-base:i386 libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libgpm2:i386
  libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libtinfo5:i386
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 2960 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12,9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

And that should install the 32-bit components you need for android studio.

Comment: i will use a virtual machine to prevent mixing 32bit with 64bit  packages